# Warning using mysqli and php classes

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting the following warning

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): in E:\xampp\htdocs\control\validate.php on line 28
```

With following code

```
class Validator
{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $port;
    private $IP;
    private $database;

    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->username = "root";
        $this->password = "root";
        $this->port = 3006;
        $this->IP = "localhost";
        $this->database = "users";
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->IP, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database, $this->port); //error here

        if( $this->mysqli->connect_errno )
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    public function validateUser( $ID, $PWD )
    {
        if( !$this->connect() )
            redirect("login.php?error=mysqli_cant_connect");
    }
}
```

I'm calling connect() from validateUser like so

```
$validator = new Validator;
$validator->validateUser( $_POST["id"], $_POST["pass"]);
```

I looked high and low all over the internet and every thread I could find but couldn't get an answer, any help? I'm still new to PHP classes and mysqli, I've used a bit of mysql extension before and it worked just fine on my current setup.

Comment: make `connect()` to `public`

Comment: What says `mysqli_connect_error()`?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Sec

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt no error appears.

Comment: I tried in my local computer and works well... Are you sure don't you have anything more involved??

Comment: @Sal00m ...I don't think so, there's another function, but I'm not using it there..... nevermind, it suddenly started working, without me changing anything. still, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have't tested this, but it might have to do with the port being a string value instead of an int. See the users comment on the official Docs. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Try casting the port as an int.

Comment: The port is an integer

Comment: As @Sal00m said, it's an integer.